# Android OpenGL shader does not get created

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader, android-mediacodec, grafika

I'm using OpenGl to apply some effects on a video. This happens in two places, one is while playing the video and the other while saving this video as a separate file.
The preview part (playing the video) works fine, but for the video saving part the shaders don't get created.

The create shader call,

```
GLES20.glCreateShader(shaderType);
```

returns 0 most of the times and occasionally creates the shader.

I'm new to OpenGl, but from my understanding I don't think there are any dependencies for creating the shader.
Could someone please help me out with this.

Comment: You may be making OpenGL calls in a thread that does not have a current OpenGL context.

Comment: If @RetoKoradi's comment doesn't get you to the answer, you'll need to tell us more about what you're doing, e.g. whether you're using one EGL context or two.

Comment: The problem was with the thread.  It did not have the OpenGL context.
Thank you @RetoKoradi and fadden